# File transfer over Wi-Fi fast - Internet over Wi-Fi slow

Tags: wireless-networking

My MacBook Air is only getting 20-25mbps Internet speed over Wi-Fi, while my wired PC gets over 80mbps. So my first thought is "Okay, my wireless router just must be slow." The problem with that is, I can consistently transfer files on Wi-Fi at over 100mbps, so the Wi-Fi itself isn't slow.

My Internet isn't the problem, since anything wired to the router can reach the max speed of 75+mbps

So I'm having trouble understanding why the Internet over Wi-Fi cannot break 25mbps while the wireless router is clearly capable.

Do wireless routers perform differently when supplying Internet than they do with just local network traffic?

Router: Linksys E3200

Wifi internet speed tested using a mid 2012 MacBook Air and an iPhone 6S Plus

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this thread on the [LinkSys](https://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/E3200-very-slow-with-Comcast/td-p/845694) website

Comment: @Burgi Thanks I did not see that thread. However it seems his issues persist even on wired connection, so our problems are a bit different. I did try disabling WMM for the hell of it, but then I couldn't connect to the router at all.

Comment: What about other QoS settings?

Comment: I actually just installed Tomato to see if that made a difference. It did not. But yeah I do not use any QoS features and just confirmed none are turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Doing NAT (without hardware acceleration) and running the Wi-Fi interface can be two of the most processor-intensive things a wireless router has to do, so it's conceivable that a router with an underpowered CPU would be at its slowest when doing both at the same time.

To test this hypothesis, consider connecting your wired PC to your router's WAN port (in place of the modem) and doing the performance test from WAN to WLAN just like you'd previously done it from LAN to WLAN. You'll probably have to give your PC a static public IP address valid on the public subnet on the WAN side of your router (for example, give it your ISP router's IP address for this test).

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought of it being a CPU issue. However, I just ran a speed test for a full minute, and the router's CPU load never went over 40%