# Fast WiFi. Fast Internet over Ethernet. Slow Internet over WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

I have a 100 Mbps internet connection which I have successfully tested with Speedtest.net to be 100 Mbps when connected using an Ethernet cable to my Windows 10 machine.

Unfortunately, the maximum Internet speed that I can get is around 50 Mbps when connected via WiFi (again checking with Speedtest.net).

According to my router and Windows I am connected to the router with a speed of around 585 Mbps. I have tested TCP transfer speeds with iperf3 on my Windows machine and using an Android app, Magic iPerf on my Samsung Galaxy S6 (has a 802.11ac wifi chip), which gives me an average speed of around 180 Mbps:

```
Connecting to host 192.168.1.132, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.161 port 50353 connected to 192.168.1.132 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  21.4 MBytes   179 Mbits/sec
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  19.4 MBytes   162 Mbits/sec
[  4]   2.00-3.01   sec  19.9 MBytes   165 Mbits/sec
[  4]   3.01-4.00   sec  20.1 MBytes   171 Mbits/sec
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  20.6 MBytes   173 Mbits/sec
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  20.1 MBytes   169 Mbits/sec
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  19.9 MBytes   167 Mbits/sec
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  21.1 MBytes   177 Mbits/sec
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  20.0 MBytes   168 Mbits/sec
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  20.5 MBytes   172 Mbits/sec
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   203 MBytes   170 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   202 MBytes   169 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

This is obviously a far from ideal scenario, but was still faster than my WiFi Internet speeds.

My router is an [Asus RT-AC68U](https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTAC68U/) which is a relatively high-end 802.11ac router. I have a USB3.0 802.11ac [Netis WF2190](http://www.netis-systems.com/Home/detail/id/96.html) wireless dongle connected to a USB 3.0 port on my PC. Both my phone and pc were connected to the 5 GHz network I set up on the router in the test above. There are no other 5 GHz networks near my house at all to interfere with.

I don't really understand what could be causing this issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1:** I think that I might be having a similar problem to [this user](https://superuser.com/questions/1013492/file-transfer-over-wi-fi-fast-internet-over-wi-fi-slow?newreg=007a421ba7eb4042b922ad3bc200330b).

**EDIT 2:** Here's a terrible attempt at trying to illustrate my problem:

I was able to get wifi transfer speeds of ~180 Mbps from my Windows PC to my Android phone:

`PC <-----> Router <----> Android`

I can only get 50 Mbps when connected to the Internet through wifi:

`PC <---- Router <---- Internet`

And I can get 100 Mbps using an ethernet cable:

`PC <==== Router <==== Internet`

Comment: The passing of packets between WAN and WLAN seems to be hard on your router. Get a better router, or even better: use a separate router/firewall/gateway box, and a separate wireless access point. Practically all of the all-in-one boxes are crap due to the selected limitations (which is happening because of the target audience). An AP from Ubiquiti can be had for less than 100 (any currency), and will deliver. Try an UniFi AP AC Pro for example. Connect it to your router using a standard ethernet cable (to a LAN port), it should at least solve the WiFi speed for now.

Comment: @JohnKeates I actually have the setup you're talking about. I bought the Asus RT-AC68U I mentioned above literally today thinking I'd use it as the WiFi AP, and am using the All-In-One router that I rent from my provider as a modem. I'll look into returning what I purchased and try and find the UniFi, or something similar.

Comment: The Asus is a consumer all-in-one box. It uses a cheap SoC connected to a cheap internal ethernet switch and an internal USB or PCI(e) bus to an 802.11 element. To get packets from wifi to anywhere else, they have to pass the SoC, which does bridging and NAT in software, possibly with basic hardware acceleration. This is slightly different from the ethernet LAN-WAN bridge/NAT as there are no ethernet frames on 802.21. This means all wireless packets most likely pass a pure software stack before getting through to the rest of the net. A 'real' AP solves that part.

Comment: Thanks for your knowledgeable advice! I feel dumb for using two AIO devices plugged into eachother now. Any other WiFi pure APs you'd recommend before I go shopping?

Comment: Well, there are mostly more expensive ones, but they don't actually help you in your current situation. The AP AC Pro ( or whatever the correct name is ;-) it's on one of their websites ) is about as expensive as the overpriced consumer stuff. Depending on your country/ISP, some decent options might be available. Here in The Netherlands, one of our ISP's sells a concurrent dual-band +DFS AP for less than the Ubiquiti stuff (almost half the price), yet performs almost as good. It's OEM stuff so it's not otherwise easy to get your hands on. Other options are more in the pro area, more expensive.

Comment: Brands for the next level (above ubnt's stuff) would be Cisco, Ruckus, xirrus, maybe even HP and Dell. A slightly lower end option for WiFi would be routerboard-based devices, and below that, EnGenius. I personally wouldn't accept anything below that, and prefer Ubiquiti and above. For routing/gateway/firewall (if the ISP modem does bridge mode or if you have a bare connection anyway), I'd start with pfSense software on sensible hardware (i.e. pre made boxes by NetGate, or a custom build), or maybe if I need lower end, something from the Mikrotik guys. At enterprise I would need Cisco/Juniper.

Comment: Awesome information. I can't thank you enough. Would it be silly to do what you first recommended and leave the routing/gateway/modem to my ISP box, and just plug in a WiFi AP? AFAIK I need the VSDL modem in the ISP box, and its essentially free.